# Why exit() not work here?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use some data to draw circles by time, update process is good, but exit not work,here is part of my code:

```
function update(data) {

        var tmp1 = group.selectAll('.circle').data(data)
        tmp1.enter().append('circle')
                .attr('cx', function(d) {coords = projection([d.long,d.lat]); return  coords[0]})
                .attr('cy', function(d) {coords = projection([d.long,d.lat]); return  coords[1]})
                .attr('r',  function(d) { return countScale(d.count)})
                .attr("stroke", function(d, i) { return color(d.name, i);}) 
                .attr("stroke-width", 2.3)
                .style('fill', function(d) { 
                        if (d.count == 0){ return 'white';}
                        if (d.count !== 0){ return color(d.name);}
                    });
                tmp1.exit().remove();
}
```

After that I use setInterval to update my data,but exit not work, the previous circle still exit.

```
setInterval(function() { update(nextDay(data)) }, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selectAll(".circle")` is selecting by the class name "circle", but you are then appending `circle` elements and not setting the class attribute to match your selector. So your exit selection will always be empty, because there are no matching elements.

Did you mean to `selectAll("circle")` (no leading `.`) to select by element name instead?

(Also, you might want a [key function](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) and to read about the [general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).)

Comment: I solved my problem, thanks a lot, glad you answer my question, your General Update Pattern tutorial help me a lot!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept this answer with the checkmark if I’ve answered your question.